# Spring Boot, Thymeleaf and strings

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hello I'm using spring boot 2.4.x and I want to use thymeleaf as my template engine.

I've added the thymeleaf starter and I've the following test

```
@Test
void name() {
    StringTemplateResolver stringTemplateResolver = new StringTemplateResolver();

    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(stringTemplateResolver);

    Context ctx = new Context();
    ctx.setVariable("franco", "prova");

    String processedTemplate = templateEngine.process("<html>${franco}</html>", ctx);

    Assertions.assertThat(processedTemplate).isEqualTo("<html>prova</html>");
}
```

but the templateEngine is not substituting the variable and the value of the processedTemplate variable is the same as the input string.

What's my fault?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thymeleaf won't process variables directly in HTML.  You either have to use the [text inlining](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining) syntax:

```
<html>[[${franco}]]</html>
```

or do it the standard way (which is to use attributes prefixed with `th:`) like this:

```
<html th:text="${franco}" />
```

or

```
<html><span th:text="${franco}" /></html>
```

(Also, as a side note [StringTemplateResolver](https://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.12.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/templateresolver/StringTemplateResolver.html) is the default resolver, so you don't have to configure it.  Your complete code can look like this.)

```
@Test
void name() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

    Context ctx = new Context();
    ctx.setVariable("franco", "prova");

    String processedTemplate = templateEngine.process("<html>[[${franco}]]</html>", ctx);
    Assertions.assertThat(processedTemplate).isEqualTo("<html>prova</html>");
}
```